# Wildfly not crating JNDI bindings for beans implementing 2 interfaces

Tags: ejb, wildfly, jndi

I am having an issues with Wildfly 15.0.0 that it's not crating a JNDI for an EJB that is implementing both local and remote interfaces. My classes are as follows:

Local interface:

```
@Local
public interface BlockingManagerRemote{ 
}
```

Remote interface:

```
@Remote
public interface BlockingManagerLocal{  
}
```

implementation:

```
@Remote({BlockingManagerRemote.class})
@Local({BlockingManagerLocal.class})
@Stateless
public class BlockingManager
        implements BlockingManagerRemote, BlockingManagerLocal {
}
```

I get the following message first:

```
2019-03-13 12:09:57,459 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYEJB0111: No jndi bindings will be created for EJB BlockingManager since no views are exposed
```

And When trying to inject this EJB in another class as follows:

```
@Remote({BusinessUserManagerRemote.class})
@Local({BusinessUserManagerLocal.class})
@Stateless
public class BusinessUserManager
        implements BusinessUserManagerLocal, BusinessUserManagerRemote {

    @EJB
    private BlockingManagerLocal blockingManager;

}
```

I get this exception:

```
2019-03-13 12:09:58,469 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."mpaymentapp-ear.ear"."mpaymentapp-service-1.0.3-SNAPSHOT.jar".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."mpaymentapp-ear.ear"."mpaymentapp-service-1.0.3-SNAPSHOT.jar".INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of subdeployment "mpaymentapp-service-1.0.3-SNAPSHOT.jar" of deployment "mpaymentapp-ear.ear"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:151)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1738)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1700)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1558)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1364)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYEE0052: Failed to install component BusinessUserManager
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ComponentInstallProcessor.deploy(ComponentInstallProcessor.java:109)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:144)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYEJB0406: No EJB found with interface of type 'com.cit.mpaymentapp.common.blocking.BlockingManagerLocal' for binding com.cit.mpaymentapp.service.registration.BusinessUserManager/blockingManager
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbInjectionSource.getResourceValue(EjbInjectionSource.java:90)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ComponentInstallProcessor.processBindings(ComponentInstallProcessor.java:263)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ComponentInstallProcessor.access$000(ComponentInstallProcessor.java:80)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ComponentInstallProcessor$1.handle(ComponentInstallProcessor.java:215)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ClassDescriptionTraversal.run(ClassDescriptionTraversal.java:54)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ComponentInstallProcessor.deployComponent(ComponentInstallProcessor.java:218)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ComponentInstallProcessor.deploy(ComponentInstallProcessor.java:101)
    ... 9 more
```

The same code was working on JBOSS EAP6. Why Wildfly is not recognizing the local interface `BlockingManagerLocal`?

Comment: In your example you have @Local on the BlockingManagerRemote class, is this just an error posting here or is it also wrong in your code? I'm assuming your interfaces actually list some methods too?

Comment: Yes, the @Local annotation is on the interface too. Both interfaces contain methods but i have omitted them from the question.

Comment: Please show your application.xml

Comment: What about my comment that you put @Local on your remote and vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should implement your Interfaces as plain java interfaces and add the annotation @LocalBean instead of @Local to your bean implementation.

Remote EJBs should be avoided. I recommend using Rest interfaces instead.